# How to avoid angular2 giant footprint

Tags: node.js, angular, ide

I am investigating the development setup for our next developments.

Requirements

- Java, WAR
- Javascript, Angular2
- JSP, Html, CSS

When doing this with eclipse-neon and nodeeclipse a simple Angular2 "Hello World" will take up giant

**100 MBytes, in words hundred megabytes**

nearly all is located in "node_modules".
Generating a WAR results in about 30 MBytes after waiting a long time.

Is there a way to reduce this giant footprint to a reasonable size?

---

As proposed I investigated both ways using **webpack** with simple "Hello World" apps

First I tried 
http://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html
. After removing **.map-files** the total size was **1.1MB**. The (packed) **WAR** comes with **250KB**

Second I tried **angular-cli**. angular-cli creates a set of config-files and a simple "Hello World". After remove **.map-files** the total size was **3.2MB**. the **WAR** comes with **490KB**.

Regarding the size both approaches looks valid. However, we will continue with the first approach since it used explicit config file for **webpack**. We need to tweak **webpack** in order to use and support **JSP**. It is not obvious how this could be done with angular-cli.

If you do not need to tweak the webpack config, you may prefer **angular-cli**

Comment: I am currently dealing with this same problem. I have yet to get any type of decent answer. People just suggest lazy loading, but I want to solve the problem before it happens and not use lazy loading as a crutch. I am very surprised after all the time it took to finally release Anguar2, it still has these types of issues with no direct solution.

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html?

Comment: @echomax no I didn't, but I will investigate webpack. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this is an experience you make when starting with angular 2 and node. The solution to this is using a **package builder like "webpack"**. I'd recommend to create a starter project with "angular-cli"
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
and start from there to add your project-specific components, libraries, ...
This makes it possible to jump right into development and testing this feature very quickly. Investigating the mighty and complexity behind that is recommended, but can be done step by step.

The command-line commands for this generated project - you can see them defined in the generated **"package.json"** - provide all you need to develop and run the code
and also 
e.g. npm run build:prod
...
preparing the code for deployment, including reducing and packing the code to an absolute minimum size (in my case from ~ 120MB to 2.7MB)